# Partial template deduction in constructors

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, c++17

**Problem:**  I'm often in a situation where some types can be deduced from the constructor's arguments, but not all:

```cpp
template <typename Res, typename Arg>
struct adder {
    adder (Arg a1, Arg a2) : a1 {a1}, a2 {a2} {}
    void compute () { res = a1 + a2; }
    Res result () { return res; }

    Arg a1, a2;
    Res res;
};
```

If I'm using `int` arguments and want to specify `unsigned` as result type, I would like to write something like:

```cpp
auto add = adder<unsigned>(42, -51);
```

…which doesn't work.  However, I don't want to explicitly mention `int`.

**Candidate solutions:** I can think of two ways to "make it work", first with a maker:

```cpp
template <typename Res>
struct wrapper {
    template <typename Arg>
    static auto make_adder (Arg a1, Arg a2) {
      return adder<Res, Arg> (a1, a2);
    }
};

auto add = wrapper<unsigned>::make_adder (42, -51);
```

Second by making sure that all types can be deduced in the constructor:

```cpp
template <typename Res, typename Arg>
struct adder_extra {
    adder_extra (Arg a1, Arg a2, Res r) : a1 {a1}, a2 {a2} {}
    void compute () { res = a1 + a2; }
    Res result () { return res; }

    Arg a1, a2;
    Res res;
};

auto add = adder_extra (42, -51, (unsigned) 0);
```

**Question:** Is there a preferred way?  Can this be solved more neatly in another fashion?

Comment: Instead of dummy `Res` in second snippet, you might pass **tag** as `std::type_identity<T>`(or `std::in_place_type_t<T>` or your one).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An option you did not mention is to do as the standard library does<sup>1</sup>, and free the maker function:

```
template <typename Res, typename Arg>
auto make_adder (Arg a1, Arg a2) {
      return adder<Res, Arg> (a1, a2);
}
```

Template argument deduction for functions allows one to specify part of the template arguments. `make_adder<unsigned>(42, -51)` is perfectly valid, as far back as C++98.

It's a workaround as well, true. But it's a prevalent and idiomatic one.

---

<sup>1</sup> - `std::make_unique`, `std::make_shared`, `std::make_optional`, `std::make_any`, `std::make_tuple`, etc.

Comment: Ah, splendid!  I believe my question was indeed "what is idiomatic," so there we are.  Will wait for others to chime in, but that seems this should be the correct answer.  It still feels unnatural to have a make function just to go around a syntactic limitation, but that's better than what I proposed!